# How does react`s useEffect hook handle value changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state value

```
const [fromAirport, setFromAirport] = useState<Airport | null>(null);
```

and I also have a custom hook that logs out the value of the passed-in argument each time its value changes as below

```
export const useUpdateLogger = (value: any) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(value);
  }, [value]);
};
```

I then use it like this `useUpdateLogger(fromAirport);`.

**Question**:  **The default value of my state variable is null. So why does the value null get logged out yet the variable has not changed?** As in it's just null so why are we logging out null and I haven't changed the variable`s variable to anything else? Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, `useEffect` is being executed when the component loads for the first time.

i.e The useEffect with an empty array as a second argument will be called on `component mount` and `component unmount`.

For example:

```
useEffect( () => {
    console.log("mounts");

    return () => console.log("unmounts");
 , []}
```

when the `second argument` is not empty then, useEffect will be called, once when the component `mounts`, it will be called every time when the variable's value is changed, and at last, when the component `unmounts`

PS: The variable inside the second argument should be passed inside an array and should be a state or a prop which is a state variable somewhere in the parent component.

For example:

```
const [variable, setVariable] = useState(0);
```

```
useEffect( () => {
    console.log("every time the value of variable is changed or when the component mounts");

    return () => console.log("unmounts");
 , [variable]}
```